# How to change the image of a PictureBox when the Ping Round Trip Time is more that 50ms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ping

I am developing an application that pings several host. The list of hosts is read from a CSV file.
When there is a response, the program displays a green tick, a red cross when the ping fails.

This works great, but I need to display a third image (like a yellow explanation mark) when the Round Trip Time is more than `50ms`.

This is my code at the moment:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    Parallel.For(0, ipAddress.Count(), (i, loopState) =>
    {
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(ipAddress[i].ToString());
        this.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate ()
        {
            pictureboxList[i].BackgroundImage = (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success) ? Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\PC\Downloads\green.png") : Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\PC\Downloads\red.png");
        });
    });
}
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You can use the `RoundtripTime`, just add an `if` condition. -- You shouldn't invoke from the DoWork event, you should report progress; or use `Image.FromFile()`, you should probably use local objects taken from the Projetc's resources, setting properties of Controls in the `ProgressChanged` event.

Comment: Hi Thanks, could you possibly provide an example?  I have tried that the `if` doesn't seem to work

Comment: Maybe. For sure not using a BackgroundWorker, though. Probably a `List<Task>` + a `Progress<T>` delegate to update the UI and calling `SendPingAsync()` , then awaiting `Task.WhenAll()`. -- If that's ok (and if someone doesn't come by with something like that in the meanwhile), I'll post it.

Comment: Okay, thanks, i'll work on that and if I can get it working then I'll post the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An simple example using a `List<Task>` to generate a sequence of Ping requests, using a collection of IP Addresses (in the form of strings) provided by the caller and uses an [IProgress<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1) delegate to update the UI (`Progress<T>` captures the current SynchronizationContext, so code executed by the delegate, is executed in Thread that initialized it; the UI Thread, here).
For each address passed to the method, a `PingAsync()` Task is added to the list.

The `PingAsync()` method calls [Ping.SendPingAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendpingasync) and reports back the results, either success or failure, as an object that can represent a [PingReply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.pingreply), a [PingException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.pingexception) or a [SocketException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketexception) in the form of a `SocketError` (the `Progress()` method translates the `SocketError` to an [IPStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ipstatus), to handle just one type of result. Add more cases if you need a more verbose / detailed response).

The Tasks generate a sequence (an `int` value) that is sent to the `Progress<T>` delegate, in case it needs it. Here, it's used to select a specific Control from the collection passed to the `PingAll()` method.

You can then handle these results in the [Progress<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) delegate, to see what happened to the current Ping request and update your Controls.

[Task.WhenAll()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall) is then awaited. It will return when all Tasks complete. A Task completes when Ping succeeds or fails or when the specified timeout has elapsed.

The 3 images used to display the result status:

- Green  - IPStatus.Success and RoundtripTime <= 30
- Yellow - IPStatus.Success and RoundtripTime > 30
- Red - IPStatus != IPStatus.Success

are taken from the Project's resources. Better not get them from the File System here, you may introduce unnecessary complexity without any advantage.

Assume you initialize the `MassPing` class and await the results of `PingAll()` using the handler of a Button.Click (note that the handler is `async`):

```
private async void btnMassPing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnMassPing.Enabled = false;
    // Create a collection of existing Controls that have a BackgroundImage property
    var controls = new Control[] { /* a list of existing Controls */ };
    // The Addresses count must match the Controls'
    var addresses = [An array of strings representing IpAddresses or Host names]
    var massPing = new MassPing();
    await massPing.PingAll(addresses, controls, 2000);
    btnMassPing.Enabled = true;
}
```

Note: for simplicity, the `PingAll()` method creates an `IProgress<T>` delegate all by itself. You may prefer to pass a delegate to this method instead, from the procedure that initializes the `MassPing` class.
This way, you don't need to pass a collection of Controls to the method.
It doesn't matter much if you use this class in a WinForms app, it does (or may) matter if you want to move the class to a Library.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MassPing
{
    private Bitmap imageRed = Properties.Resources.Red;
    private Bitmap imageGreen = Properties.Resources.Green;
    private Bitmap imageYellow = Properties.Resources.Yellow;

    public async Task PingAll(string[] addresses, Control[] controls, uint timeout = 2000)
    {
        // Add more checks on the arguments
        if (addresses.Length != controls.Length) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Collections length mismatch");
        }

        var obj = new object();
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        var progress = new Progress<(int sequence, object reply)>(report => {
            lock (obj) {
                // Use the reply Status value to set any other Control. In this case, 
                // it's probably better to have a UserControl that shows multiple values
                var status = IPStatus.Unknown;
                if (report.reply is PingReply pr) {
                    status = pr.Status;
                    Bitmap img = status is IPStatus.Success
                        ? pr.RoundtripTime > 30 ? imageYellow : imageGreen
                        : imageRed;
                    controls[report.sequence].BackgroundImage?.Dispose();
                    controls[report.sequence].BackgroundImage = img;
                }
                else if (report.reply is SocketError socErr) {
                    if (socErr == SocketError.HostNotFound) {
                        status = IPStatus.DestinationHostUnreachable;
                    }
                    controls[report.sequence].BackgroundImage?.Dispose();
                    controls[report.sequence].BackgroundImage = imageRed;
                }
            }
        });

        // Add all tasks
        for (int seq = 0; seq < addresses.Length; seq++) {
            tasks.Add(PingAsync(addresses[seq], (int)timeout, seq, progress));
        }
        // Could use some exception handling 
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    private async Task PingAsync(string ipAddress, int timeOut, int sequence, IProgress<(int seq, object reply)> progress)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[32];
        var ping = new Ping();

        try {
            var options = new PingOptions(64, true);
            PingReply reply = await ping.SendPingAsync(ipAddress, timeOut, buffer, options);
            progress.Report((sequence, reply));
        }
        catch (PingException pex) {
            if (pex.InnerException is SocketException socEx) {
                progress.Report((sequence, socEx.SocketErrorCode));
            }
        }
        finally {
            ping.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks I just understand what I need to do here at this line?  `var addresses = [An array of strings representing IpAddresses or Host names]`?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the initial question, I think it should be enough :

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Parallel.For(0, ipAddress.Count(), (i, loopState) =>
        {
            Ping ping = new Ping();
            PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(ipAddress[i].ToString());
            this.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate ()
            {
                if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    if (pingReply.RoundtripTime > 50)
                        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\PC\Downloads\yellow.png");
                    else
                        Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\PC\Downloads\green.png");
                }
                else
                {
                    Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\PC\Downloads\red.png");
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

However, don't load images from disk again and again, keep it in variables to save disk access.