# How to run a function when an asynchronous Ping is successful?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got a XML document loaded with IP's (and other data) that I'm using the [Ping.SendAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendasync?view=net-7.0) to ping asynchronously. I need to run a function that updates the "Last online" date whenever a ping is successful, but as the pings are ran asynchronously (and have to be, since there may be thousands of them).

At the moment, I have no idea how to do that with the way my code works. I keep seeing information about "await" as an option to wait to do things asynchronously, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to use that with Ping.SendAsync.

The intended result is that I ping a device, get a response, and if that response is valid, I update the XML document with the current time. I have everything done and working except the "If that response is valid, do X" part.

The code in question:

```
public int ping(string ip)
    {
        //test if IP is valid
        System.Net.IPAddress ipAddress = null;
        bool isValidIp = System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse(ip, out ipAddress);
        if (!isValidIp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid IP");
            return 0;
        }
        AutoResetEvent waiter = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        Ping pingSender = new Ping();
        // When the PingCompleted event is raised,
        // the PingCompletedCallback method is called.
        // it is essentially used for error checking after the ping is completed
        pingSender.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(PingCompletedCallback);

        //Create buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted
        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        //wait 12 seconds for reply
        int timeout = 12000;


        //Options for transmission
        //first one is number of nodes
        //second is whether the packet cant be fragmented
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions(64, true);
            //Console.WriteLine("Time to live: {0}", options.Ttl);
            //Console.WriteLine("Don't fragment: {0}", options.DontFragment);

            //Send ping asynchronously, when the callback completes it wakes up this thread
            pingSender.SendAsync(ip, timeout, buffer, options, waiter);
            
            return 1;
    }
```

The Call back function

```
    private static void PingCompletedCallback(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //if ping canceled, write to console
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ping canceled.");
            // Let the main thread resume.
            // UserToken is the AutoResetEvent object that the main thread
            // is waiting for.
            ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
        }

        //If an error occured, write the exception to the console
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ping failed:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Error.ToString());

            //Let main thread resume
            ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
        }
        PingReply reply = e.Reply;
        DisplayReply(reply);
    }
```

I was originally going to put the code to modify the date below the "DisplayReply(reply);" line in the callback, but the issue is that I need to know which row the device is in, and I can't exactly pass that to the callback function, since its called by a function not in my code.

Comment: BTW (but unrelated): I suggest following common C# naming conventions.

Comment: Call `SendPingAsync` instead of `SendAsync`. That will get you started down a better path.

Comment: SendPingASync with Await and using the return value seems like it could accomplish what im looking for...
using examples here
https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/Ping/SendPingAsync/php-ping-sendpingasync-method-examples.html

Comment: [How to change the image of a PictureBox when the Ping Round Trip Time is more that 50ms?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68835340/7444103) -- Similar (VB.NET): [Ping multiple device names (hostname) on the Network](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66013390/7444103)

Answer (score 0):

Once you use `SendPingAsync` instead of the (very old) `SendAsync`, your code will clean up nicely:

```
public async Task<int> PingAsync(string ip)
{
  //test if IP is valid
  System.Net.IPAddress ipAddress = null;
  bool isValidIp = System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse(ip, out ipAddress);
  if (!isValidIp)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid IP");
    return 0;
  }
  Ping pingSender = new Ping();

  //Create buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted
  string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
  byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

  //wait 12 seconds for reply
  int timeout = 12000;

  //Options for transmission
  //first one is number of nodes
  //second is whether the packet cant be fragmented
  PingOptions options = new PingOptions(64, true);

  //Send ping asynchronously
  try
  {
    PingReply reply = await pingSender.SendPingAsync(ip, timeout, buffer, options);
    DisplayReply(reply);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Ping failed:");
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
  }

  return 1;
}
```